# Getting Null Pointer and I have no idea why

Tags: android, xml, class, layout, nullpointerexception

I am having a `NPE` on some code and I have no clue why.  I am sure it is something trivial, but I can't seem to find it - here is what I am trying to do.

Snap a photo, detect faces, if there are no faces then display the image on an `ImageView` and allow the user the option to snap another photo.

Here is my code:

```
if (facesFound < 1) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.false_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badPicText);
    textView.setText(R.string.noFaceFive);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
}
```

this is inside my method:

```
private void detectFaces() {
    //Here is the method I use to snap a photo then detect for faces:
}
public void processCameraImage(Intent intent) {
    setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout); // detectlayout
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view); // image_view
    cameraBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
    detectFaces();
}
```

The odd thing is, when a face is detected, it works just fine - and puts them image on an `ImageView` saying it did, as so

```
if (facesFound > 0){
    //face detection code
    //write the bmp to an output stream, compress
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGoodPic);
    textView.setText(R.string.yesFace);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
}
```

Anyone know where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

*EDIT*:  the app is crashing when the app detects no faces and I try to write the photo and some text to the `ImageView`.

*EDIT*:  Here is the `logcat`:

```
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.project.dtf/com.project.dtf.DTF}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3589)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3631)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:129)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2137)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.project.dtf.DTF.detectFaces(DTF.java:130)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.project.dtf.DTF.processCameraImage(DTF.java:90)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.project.dtf.DTF.onActivityResult(DTF.java:57)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
11-18 19:42:39.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3585)
```

*EDIT*:  Still having issues =/

Here are both calls:

```
if (facesFound < 1) {
    setContentView(R.layout.detectfalse);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.false_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badPicText);
    textView.setText(R.string.noFace);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
}
```

*AND*

```
if (facesFound > 0) {
    showToast(this, "Face Detected!");
    //do stuff

    setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGoodPic);
    textView.setText(R.string.yesFace);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);
}
```

Keep in mind, I did `setContentView` in this method:

```
public void processCameraImage(Intent intent) {

    setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout); // detectlayout
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view); // image_view
    cameraBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
    detectFaces();
}
```

before the `facedetect` class is even called, is that where I am going wrong?

Comment: What line of code does the NPE's stack trace say it's coming from?

Comment: these lines:   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.false_view);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badPicText);
            textView.setText(R.string.noFaceFive);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);

Comment: are you sure that you made setContentView and that the layout you set it to contains R.id.false_view and R.id.badPicText? Is bitmap bitmap565 set? can you provide us with the exact stacktrace of the exception? please copy paste the whole exception. And tell us the exact line it refers to. Thank you :)

Comment: So here is where I think my issue is, now that you say that...in my method processCameraImage, I set the content view to detectlayout.xml, but really I want the content view to be detectfalse if the face detect didn't find faces, and detectlayout if it did - I think I am awry there and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: line 130 is:   textView.setText(R.string.noFaceFive);  btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use two layouts? I'm almost sure that your problem is using `findViewById(R.id.false_view)` without calling setContentView(R.layout.blabla_whatever), where blabla_whatever.xml contains `false_view`.

Why don't you just do something like:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);    
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGoodPic);
if (facesFound > 0){    
    //face detection code    
    //write the bmp to an output stream, compress    
    textView.setText(R.string.yesFace);    
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);    
}else{
    textView.setText(R.string.noFaceFive);    
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);    
}
```

Again... unless you show a completely different layout, you wouldn't need to use different `ImageViews` nor `TextView` to show the result.

If you insist in having different layouts, make sure to call the `setContentView(R.layout.noface_layout)` before using the `findViewById` method.

**Edit**

Now I know why you think you need another layout. You can use just one layout though. This is what you can do:

```
OnClickListener editPhoto = new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(){
       // edit photo stuff
   }
};

OnClickListener takePhotoAgain = new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(){
       // take the photo again
   }
};

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);    
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGoodPic);
Button actionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_id);

if (facesFound > 0){    
    //face detection code    
    //write the bmp to an output stream, compress    
    textView.setText(R.string.yesFace);    
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);    
    actionButton.setText("Face detected, edit it!");
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(editPhoto);
}else{
    textView.setText(R.string.noFaceFive);    
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap565);    
    actionButton.setText("You are too ugly for me, take another picture!");
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(takePhotoAgain);
}
```

Comment: Well, one of my layouts has a button on it that allows for the pic to be taken again, and says Face Not Detected!  While another layout says Face Detected!  And has a button that allows the user to crop the face and use it as an avatar...so I really need 2 different layouts...one for when faces are detected, and another for when they aren't.

Comment: Holy crap, what an oversight on my part - thanks Cristian!  Is having different layouts poor coding?  I want to be able to use one, but each layout displays different attributes =/

Comment: Having different layouts is fine when the structure changes radically (for instance, if you have a different structure for both portrait and landscape). In your case, as I demonstrated in my answer, you can just modify some elements of your layout and you are good to go.

Comment: In turn, would having say 3 layouts that are kind of different acceptable, IE:  if I wanted a sound that says 'File Saved' on one, and a picture on another?  I don't want to bloat code this though the app is pretty small

Comment: The more layouts, the more complex code you will generate... most of the cases you can do tricks like the one above.

Comment: Ahhh I see!  I actually modded the code a bit (I realized I have to use 2 layouts =/) adding the setContentView before all the code and both results (faces detected, and faces not detected) still go to the layout result.xml rather than one or the other....I edited in my OP the code...I am sure I am missing something trivial again.

Comment: So, essentially both are going to the same layout, rather than one to detectfalse, and one to detectlayout.